# Keycloak row level permissions

Tags: oauth-2.0, permissions, keycloak, openid-connect

I would like to use Keycloak as an authentication and authorization server in my existing project,I want to achieve **row level** (database table) permissions, I'm thinking to create a resource for each row and group them by type (the type is the name of the table), I'm wondering if there exists any better solution ?
Any suggestions are appreciated.